# Horizontally centering an absolute div that will align to the left when screen isn't large enough

Tags: css, css-position, centering

I have a div that is absolute positioned (because it holds sub-divs that are themselves absolutely positioned), that I want horizontally centered.

I can achieve that using the following CSS

```
width : 512px;
position : absolute;
left : 50%;
margin-left :-256px; // half width of div
```

(complete test in http://jsbin.com/eruwep/2/edit)

However when the window isn't large enough, the div overflows to the left.

Is there a way to have it centered when the page is large enough, but left-justified otherwise (using just CSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `position: absolute` for the container? If it's just because you want its absolutely positioned children to be positioned relative to their container, you don't need `absolute` for that. Any value other than `static` will do that.

Changing the CSS you mentioned in your question to the following will make it work:

```
width : 512px;
position : relative;
margin : auto;
```

Example in: http://jsbin.com/eruwep/3/edit

Comment: position relative on the container works in my case, good point!

Answer (score 1):

You could try media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/RfUZj/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when the element has "position: absolute" (http://jsfiddle.net/T7w6z/)

Comment: I was giving you an easier more semantic alternative, position absolute isn't nice if you want elements to move around, change your code to use margin: 0 auto;

Comment: The sub-divs are positioned relative to their parent container (so position: absolute), rather than relative to their default position (position:relative)